# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json4s.JsonAST$JValue

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, bazel

I am trying a POC on kafka where I am loading a dataset to a topic and reading from it. I am trying to create a struct as follow to apply to the data  that I will read from kafka topic:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{MapType, StringType, StructField, StructType} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
//import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.j 
//import org.json4s._ 
//import org.json4s.na

val df = spark
    .read
    .format("kafka")
    .options(Admin.commonOptions)
    .option("subscribe", topic)
    .load()
  df.printSchema()

  val personStringDF = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  println("personStringDF--")
  personStringDF.show()
  personStringDF.printSchema()

  val schemaTopic: StructType = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField(name = "col1", dataType = StringType, nullable = false),
      StructField(name = "col2", dataType = StringType, nullable = false)
   ))
```

My BUILD file :

```
java_library(
    name = "spark",
    exports = [
        "@maven//:org_apache_spark_spark_core_2_12",
        "@maven//:org_apache_spark_spark_sql_2_12",
        "@maven//:org_apache_spark_spark_unsafe_2_12",
        "@maven//:org_apache_spark_spark_tags_2_12",
        "@maven//:org_apache_spark_spark_catalyst_2_12",
        "@maven//:com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_annotations",
        "@maven//:com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_core",
        "@maven//:com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_databind",
        "@maven//:com_typesafe_play_play_json_2_12_2_9_1",
        "@maven//:org_json4s_json4s_ast_2_12_4_0_0",
        "@maven//:org_json4s_json4s_jackson_2_12_4_0_0"
,

        ],
)
```

but getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json4s/JsonAST$JValue`
Can anybody help here not sure why am I getting this?
(running this code with Bazel I have a workspace file as well all these dependencies mentioned there this is runtime error bazel build is successful)

Comment: Does Bazel default to creating a fat jar? Also, your code isn't even using json4s. What is `Admin.commonOptions`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Admin.commonOptions contains bootstrap server, kafka security protocol which is required to connect to Kafka topic (topic is in event streams)

Comment: I understand that part, but if that is not using `json4s`, then your error shouldn't be happening. Spark doesn't need json4s, AFAIK. Also didn't answer my first question

Comment: Even I m not sure if I don't create struct code works fine without error - @OneCricketeer

Comment: Can you please show your import statements?

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{MapType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.j
//import org.json4s._
//import org.json4s.na`

Comment: If your imports are actually commented, then you should remove the code. And again, does Bazel create a fat jar or not?

Comment: yes it creates jar everytime there's a change in code

Comment: Sure, but does that jar **contain the dependencies** (i.e. a fat jar)

Comment: e.g. You want a deployable JAR, not a library - https://www.baeldung.com/bazel-build-tool#deployable-jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239096/discussion-between-akene-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: Doesn't matter where you deploy. The JAR itself still needs all the `exports` targets as part of it. Otherwise, you'll get these `NoClassDefFoundError` errors because, as the error says, the classpath doesn't include the external dependencies

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by downgrading version of JSON dependencies to
3.6.6 in WORKSPACE file

```
"org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.12:3.6.6",
"org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.6.6",
"org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:3.6.6",
"org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.12:3.6.6",
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed some dependent json4s libs.

Bazel require to explicitly enumerate all needed dependencies in build file.